# Prove that $(A^c \cup B^c) - A = A^c $

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

Prove that for any two sets A,B, we have $(A^c \cup B^c) - A = A^c $

*Attempt*

Let $x \in\ (A^c \cup B^c) - A$

Then, $x \in\ A^c$ or $x \in\ B^c$ and $x \notin\ A$

$x \in\ A^c$ or $x \in\ B^c$ and $x \in\ A^c$

Comment: your idea looks fine to me.. you could continue doing the same i guess... what is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here $(A^c \cup B^c)-A = (A^c\cup B^c)\cap A^c=(A^c\cap A^c)\cup (B^c\cap A^c)=A^c\cup (B^c\cap A^c)=A^c \cup (B\cup A)^c=[A\cap (B\cup A)]^c=[(A\cap B)\cup (A\cap A)]^c=[(A\cap B)\cup A]^c=A^c$ because $A\cap B \subset A$

Answer (score 2):

We can exchange $B^C$ for $B$ (with another choice of $B$, duh), to save some time writing it down. Then you have
$$(A^C \cup B) \setminus A = (A^C \cup B) \cap A^C = (A^C \cap A^C) \cup (A^C \cap B) = A^C \cup (A^C \cap B) = A^C \cap (\Omega \cup B) = A^C \cap \Omega = A^C$$
Where $\Omega = \emptyset^C$ is the full space.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is basically one step more than you already had, but written out a bit more formally.

Expand the definitions, starting at the most complex side: what are the elements $\;x\;$ of the set $\;(A^c \cup B^c) - A\;$?  Just calculate:
\begin{align}
& x \in (A^c \cup B^c) - A \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"definition of $\;-\;$"} \\
& x \in A^c \cup B^c \;\land\; x \not\in A \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"definition of $\;\cup\;$"} \\
& (x \in A^c \;\lor\; x \in B^c) \;\land\; x \not\in A \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"definition of $\;^c\;$, twice"} \\
& (x \not\in A \;\lor\; x \not\in B) \;\land\; x \not\in A \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"logic: use $\;x \not\in A\;$ on other side of $\;\land\;$"} \\
& (\text{true} \;\lor\; x \not\in B) \;\land\; x \not\in A \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"logic: simplify"} \\
& \ldots \\
\end{align}
Complete this, and by set extensionality the original statement now follows.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:$$A -B=A\cap B ^ C$$
$$A\cap (B\cup C)=(A\cap B)\cup(A\cap C)$$